# Commenting independent if statement affects the preceding one

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the following script commenting/ uncommenting the `if barstate.isconfirmed` block affects the results of the preceding `if barstate.isnew` block. Why?
(please run this script on 1M timeframe for BTCUSDT.P on Bybit)

```
// Run this on 1M timeframe for BTCUSDT.P on Bybit
//@version=5
indicator("HTF bar_index",  overlay = true)

type htfData
    int             htfBi

htfF1(htfData _htf) =>
    _htf.htfBi := bar_index
    _htf

var htfD = htfData.new()
var naHtfD = htfData.new()

htfD := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "3M", (timeframe.period == "3M") ? htfF1(htfD) : na, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
htfD := na(htfD) ? naHtfD : htfD

if barstate.isnew
    lb = label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(htfD.htfBi), style =  label.style_label_down, color = color.rgb(70, 255, 240))

// if the following block is commented then the above block prints labels from the 0's bar
// but if the folloiwing block is uncommented the labels only appear starting from Dec'20, the (3'rd 3M bar close)
// if barstate.isconfirmed
//  lb2 = label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(htfD.htfBi), style =  label.style_label_up, color = color.yellow)


plotchar(na(htfD) ? na : htfD.htfBi, "htfD.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the maximum number of labels in each script is 50(the total number of labels may fluctuate slightly above the limit); once a new label is printed, the oldest label is removed.

The limit can be increased up to 500 with the `max_labels_count=` parameter of the main function (indicator/strategy).

> max_labels_count (const int) The number of last label drawings
> displayed. Possible values: 1-500. The count is approximate; more
> drawings than the specified count may be displayed. Optional. The
> default is 50.

Note that label function calls with NA coordinates are not shown on the chart, but are also counted toward the limit.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Limitations.html#line-box-and-label-limits